# Not able to see localhost:port/sample/OpenApi.json after configuring jetty server with swagger-ui

Tags: jersey, swagger-ui, openapi

i have configured a jersey servlet for exposing swagger ui using the configuration mentioned here.
[Link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/2.0/java/java-jersey2-resourceinit/src/main/java/io/swagger/sample/MyApplication.java).

```
@ApplicationPath("/sample")
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    /**
     * Configure the Jersey application that runs within Jetty.
     */
    public JerseyApplication(@Context ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI();
        Info info = new Info()
                .title("Swagger Sample App Bootstrap code")
                .description("This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger " +
                        "at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, " +
                        "you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.")
                .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/");

        oas.info(info);
        SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
                .openAPI(oas)
                .prettyPrint(true)
                .resourcePackages(Stream.of("com.rest.resources").collect(Collectors.toSet()));

        try {
            new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder()
                    .servletConfig(servletConfig)
                    .application(this)
                    .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig)
                    .buildContext(true);
        } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

then i configured this servlet to a Jetty server

```
@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<ServletContainer> servletRegistrationBean(@Context ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        ServletRegistrationBean<ServletContainer> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new ServletContainer(), "/rest/*");
        registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyApplication.class.getName());
        return registration;
    }
```

my application is UI is up, but i am not seeing localhost:port/sample/openapi.json its getting redirected to main page of ui.
same json is used to render swagger ui , which is also not showing up.

not sure where i am missing the configuration.

was trying to upgrade swagger to latest swagger v3 on legacy code